# C# Decoupling Logging from Class

Tags: c#, logging, unity-game-engine, exception

I am using game engine Unity, but that shouldn't make a difference.
Currently my Armoury class is calling the logger, I have already decoupled it by putting my exception handling try catch in a different class, is this fine or is there a way to decouple logging even more?

```
public class Armoury : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Logging logger;

    public void Buy(int unitId)
    {
         logger.OutOfRange("unitId not present in list", unitId, PurchasbleUnits);

         //Do other stuff
    }
}

public class Logging
{
    public void OutOfRange(string error, int id, IList list)
    {
        try
        {
            list.Contains(id);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.Log(ex + " Custom: " + error);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @JamesHogle too hypothetical for Codereview.se . We do not like things like `//Do other stuff`

Comment: When you ask if this is 'fine' are you looking for an opinion on whether what you are doing makes sense?  Because, no it doesn't.  That should be a simple 'if' and it's way convoluted as is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn't reduce *coupling*. What you did by extracting that `Logging` class, is reduce the number of *responsibilities* of the `Armoury` class - which is good - but not *good enough* to reduce coupling.

> ```
> public class Armoury : MonoBehaviour
> {
>     private Logging logger;
>
>     public void Buy(int unitId)
>     {
>          logger.OutOfRange("unitId not present in list", unitId, PurchasbleUnits);
>
>          //Do other stuff
>     }
> }
> ```

To reduce the coupling between the `Armoury` class and the concrete implementation of the `Logging` class, you need to introduce an interface, and *depend* on that instead of depending on the concrete implementation:

```
private readonly ILogger;

public Armoury(ILogger logger)
{
    _logger = logger;
}
```

By *depending on an abstraction*, you're no longer tied to the concrete implementation of the `ILogger`, and by *injecting it into the constructor*, you can now control that *dependency* from the outside.

Now, an interface shouldn't be designed to change - and right now `ILogger` would look something like this:

```
public interface ILogger
{
    void OutOfRange(string error, int id, IList list);
}
```

...that's not what a logger usually does (one would expect methods like `Info(string)`, `Warn(string)`, and `Error(string,Exception)`), and that interface is going to change every time you need something new to look for - the implementation is *leaking* into the abstraction, and that's yet another design smell. As for the implementation, I doubt that works as intended, last I checked `IEnumerable<T>.Contains()` returned a Boolean, and you're discarding the return value... not sure you'll catch anything other than an `ArgumentNullException` in that `catch` block (see [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb339118(v=vs.110).aspx)).

---

I'd strongly recommend you take your **actual, complete, working code** over to [Code Review](http://www.codereview.stackexchange.com) for a fruitful peer review, once you get your code to work as intended.